# how to use the TWebbrowser on a diffent cache?

Tags: delphi, browser, ole, twebbrowser

I want to build an  Internet Browser just like any other web browser or Internet Explorer except that each window should use a unique name for cache. Any ideas? Or any third party components?

Comment: I don't think you want to make your own web browser (that would take a few years and require *a lot* of technical expertice). What you really want to do is to write your own shell for *Internet Explorer*, or some other browser engine.

Comment: @Andreas his question names TWebBrowser which essentially is IE. Naturally it would make more sense to pick something more easily extended.

Comment: @David: Yes, I saw the title. Anyhow, I feel I would need more details about the OP's requirements to say something about the issue.

Comment: Some capital letters, removal of typos and explanation and background would help.

Comment: Why each windows should have a separate cache? This way each window won't find data in the cache and end up to reload data that could be already in the cache, making your cache mechanism very inefficient.

Comment: OP must have a reason for it. :-)

Comment: Actually, the fact that the question has been asked does not mean that there is a good reason for it. IMHO, the vast majority of questions that do not have a good answer are because the wrong question has been asked. I am curious to know what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend that you ditch TWebBrowser, and find out if TEmbeddedWB (alternative IE/shelldocview wrapper ) provides you with the ability to specify a different cache per instance. if not, then I recommend you ditch IE completely, and look for a webkit based browser control for Delphi, such as the Chromium-for-delphi wrappers.