# how to use TEmbeddedWB or TWebbrowser in separate instance?

Tags: delphi, cookies, twebbrowser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use the TWebbrowser on a diffent cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980359/how-to-use-the-twebbrowser-on-a-diffent-cache)

i wanted Twebbrowser or TEmbeddedWB to open in separate instance. like login into multiple accounts. i think its done with cookies, anyone could help me?

Comment: Don't create a new question for the exact same issue as a pervious question. Instead, edit (or rewrite entirely) the original question, to include the new information. (And, yes, this seems like a much better question than the last one.)

Comment: Next time edit your other question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be barking up the wrong tree here. After a long look at this type of issue over a number of months I came to the conclusion that the only way programmatically to have separate embedded browsers using different caches was to have them in different applications and run the applications as different users. I suspect that the cache configuration is built into any embedded browser so that it works seamlessly with the equivalent actual browser, i.e. it can share cookies, etc. I would be suprised if you find anything else that works ;-)

Comment: it is possible, the Firefox(With Cookiepie) and portable chrome will work. But i wanted to create my own, i try using TEmbeddedWB you can create a separate cache but sadly they shared cookies. i hope there somebody else could help me make it work.